# Trying to Figure out Makefiles

Tags: makefile, command-prompt

So, I am brand new to makefiles, and I am horrible on the command prompt. So I want to make sure my syntax is correct.

I have three files:

```
main.cpp
Blob.cpp
Blob.h
```

I would create a file (in notepad or something) called makefile.make and in it the text would read:

```
all:
g++ main.cpp Blob.cpp Blob.h -o hello
```

I then run in command prompt

```
make
```

and the file will be created? Is this correct? They are all in the same directory, along with some other folders that VS2012 put in there.

Comment: (1) You probably don't want to specify the `.h` file in the command line and *do* want to specify it as a dependency. (2) You are not taking advantage of `make`'s strengths here; the point is that `make` can notice when dependencies are newer than their dependents and thereby know what work needs to be done.

Comment: @dmckee you've lost me a little. What would I need to change for the syntax to be correct?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
hello:main.cpp Blob.cpp
[TAB] g++ main.cpp Blob.cpp -o hello
```

Name it as `Makefile` or `makefile`. You can run just `make` to build it. Else name it anything you like, ex `mymakefile` and `run make -f mymakefile` to build it

Get fresh with [basic `makefile rules`](http://sagarsakre.blogspot.com/2012/09/understanding-makefile-for-beginners.html)

Comment: no it wont. beacause the target name is hello. which is the output file name

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to rebuild the executable when every any file has changed, use

```
all: hello

hello: main.cpp Blob.cpp Blob.h
    g++ -o hello main.cpp Blob.cpp
```

If you want separate compilation you do

```
all: hello

hello: main.o Blob.o
    g++ -o hello main.o Blob.o

main.o: main.cpp Blob.h
    g++ -o main.o main.cpp

Blob.o: Blob.cpp Blob.h
    g++ -o Blob.o Blob.cpp
```

In both cases we tell make what file are dependencies (that is, if those files change we need to rebuild) in addition to specifying the work to be done.

Comment: @SagarSakre It is redundant, but it is also a common idiom because (when you know more) it lets you use a variable to specify the dependencies of the default target.

Comment: yeah in general makefile rule it is used. for the current problem we can ignore it

Comment: Technically, `all` is not there because it lets you use a variable.  You could use a variable even without `all`.  `all` (or similar) is there because often you want to have more than one final result in a single makefile (you want to build `hello` but also `goodbye` or whatever).  Then `all` lists all the final results as prerequisites, to ensure they're all up to date.

Answer (score -1):

Google "makefile tutorial" and you'll find plenty of sites.

The commands to run have to be preceded by a <kbd>Tab</kbd> character, so it should be:

```
all:
        g++ main.cpp Blob.cpp -o hello
```

Make sure you're not using an editor that converts <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters to spaces.

Comment: Again, this would *always* rebuild the target even when not needed except that the command line is wrong: the header file should not be named.

Comment: @dmckee I already removed the .h file. I agree that this will recompile unconditionally, there's no harm in that. When he learns more about makefiles he can make use of conditional compilation.